# Add all column values that are equal to row value SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table of records each with its own creation date and closure date. I am trying to create a graph that will show the number of open and closed records on each day. So far, i've set up a binary matrix that will display a 1 if the record was open on a certain month and 0 otherwise. So, if i wanted to find the total on a certain week, i could just use a RunningValue to sum all the rows for a certain column. Unfortunately, i cannot seem to find a way to graph open and closed records on the same bar graph. So far, ive created a column in the query that has the number of the closed week. I assumed that i could just add these all up if they equal the current week but this doesnt seem to work. I used the following expression (the comparison is weird because i thought it might have something to do with comparing to values to each other) obviously this is me just testing :

```
'=CINT(Fields!Ident_Week.Value) & " / " & Fields!Close_Week.Value & " = " & SUM(IIF(CINT(Fields!Ident_Week.Value)/CINT(Fields!Close_Week.Value)=1,1,0))'
```

Im tempted now (embaressingly so) to just create 52 variables and assign the values that way. But i thought id ask here first. What do you think the best way is to find the closed records created on a certain week? Im using SSRS 2008 R2

a sample of my dataset is below (only relavent information is displayed)

```
Ident_Week   Closed_Week   Ident_Date   Closed_Date   Jan   Feb   ....   Dec
     1            3          1/1/13       1/15/13      1      0           0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be over complicating the dataset a little.

Try using UNPIVOT as below:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6270c/6

You should be able to do what you need with this. Let me know if you need any further explanation.